# Como puedo aplicar operatorias algebraicas a un dataframe en r

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe, rstudio

Hola tengo un dataframe en R de la siguiente forma (mxn):

```
a  b  c  d ... n
 
1  1  6  8 ... 

2  7  9  10 ...

3  3  4  2 ... 

4  .  .  . ... 

5  .  .  . ... 

m  .  .  . ...
```

Como puedo generar un data frame nuevo que mantenga los mismos nombres de las columnas y las filas sean completadas con el logaritmo del elemento por el elemento

```
 a          b             c          d ... n 

log(1)*1    log (1)*1                    ...  log(n)*n 

log(2)*2    log (7)*7

   .
   .
   .

log(m)*m
```

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Diego a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: En el caso que todos los valores sean numéricos, entiendo que sería algo así `log(df) * df`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, no pensé que fuera tan simple y me complique generando  lo siguiente:

dataframe.log <- function(data)

{for(i in 1:ncol(data))

  {   dataframe.vector <- data[,i]

      data2 <- data[,i]

      dataframe.vector <- log(dataframe.vector)*data[,i]

      data[,i]<-dataframe.vector
    
}
  return(data)
}

ex.dataframe <- dataframe.log(data)

pander(ex.dataframe)

Comment: Es normal, lo has intentando resolver como lo harías en cualquier lenguaje que no sea R, por supuesto que es válido, pero en el paradigma de R no tiene sentido hacerlo así por que la aritmética y las funciones ya entienden naturalmente las colecciones de datos como  vectores, matrices, listas, etc.